# HttpRequest over mobile connection fails but no error is thrown?

Tags: android, error-handling, timeout, apache-commons-httpclient

In the android app that I am writing I access the MySql Database using Php. 
I use AsyncTask with HttpClient. The code works fine when used over Wifi.
But when using 2G/3G it randomly fails.

At first I did not set either ConnectionTimeOut or SOTimeOut then it would keep going indefinitely. After setting the timeout it closes after timeout period.

There are no exceptions thrown during this period.
This is the doInBackground part of my asynctask

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    ProgressDialog pd;

    public MyAsyncTask(Context context) 
    {
        pd=new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        pd.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        String url="<php url>";
        String line = "";
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        try 
        {
            final HttpParams hp = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(hp, 15000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(hp, 15000);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(hp);
            HttpGet formData = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(formData);

            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
            InputStream is=entity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            Log.i("Tag","1. "+e.toString());
            return e.toString();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) 
        {
            Log.i("Tag","2. "+e.toString());
            return e.toString();
        }
        catch (ConnectTimeoutException e)
        {
            Log.i("Tag","3. "+e.toString());
            return e.toString();
        }
        catch (SocketTimeoutException e)
        {
            Log.i("Tag","4. "+e.toString());
            return e.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.i("Tag","5. "+e.toString());
            return e.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("Tag","6. "+e.toString());
            return e.toString();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        Log.i("Tag","Result : "+result );
        pd.dismiss();
        //tv - textview 
        tv.setText(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

None of the catch statements are executed.The PostExecute simply logs a empty string.I hope some one can shed some light on the issue, or at least the best way to handle this.

I have updated to show my complete asynctask class.Not much difference as you can see.But i noticed something new , when this situation occurs i quickly typed the url in the browser (Chrome) and the same this happened , there was no output.
But an error message was shown with 504 error, and if i refreshed the screen by pulling down i got the output. But if i retyped the url i got the same error.

Comment: L`After setting the timeout it closes after timeout period.

There are no exceptions thrown during this period.`. Impossible. You will have a ConnectTimeoutException or SocketTimeoutException then. We cannot see what you do with `sb`  and the return value of doInBackground.

Comment: `return e.toString();`. Better: `return e.getMessage();`. Yet better: `return "IOException: " + e.getMessage();` and so on.

Comment: @greenapps i have edited to show my entire AsyncTask class , and a few other things i noticed yestarday. Will try with getMessage() ,.